# Is it possible to make std container to use the default operator new?

Tags: c++

I replaced `operator new` with my own implementation. I would like to use my `operator new` for every call to `new` in my program except some cases like `std` containers.

Is it possible to make `std` container to use the default `operator new`? For example, `std::list`.

Comment: You can provide your own allocator that does whatever you would like.

Comment: Once you have replaced the standard `opearor new` with your own, the standard one is gone. You cannot refer to it anywhere in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

When any compilation unit replaces an `operator new()`, it is effectively replaced for all compilation units in the program.    That means all usages of or references to that variant of `operator new()` will resolve to the replacement.    The default allocators in the standard containers are affected as much as any other code in the program.

The scheme for replacing `operator new()` and its variants is all-or-nothing i.e.  you don't get some usages of `operator new()` resolving to the default version and others resolving to the replacement.

You can provide a allocator for your containers that uses some means to obtain raw memory other than your replacement `operator new()`.